# Named Credential Not Working with Bitly Integration

Tags: namedcredentials

I have used Named Credential to integrate with Bitly. But getting an error as Forbidden in the logs.
Below is my code:

```
public class BitlyService {
    
          
    public String shorten( String url ) {   
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();     
        req.setEndpoint('callout:Bitly/v4/shorten');     
        req.setMethod('POST');  
        req.setHeader('Authorization',' Bearer e8a7e213ed1dd3c46cd181583a335dc5bf16d33e');
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        req.setHeader('Accept','*/*');
        string websiteToshorten=url;
        req.setBody(
          '{' +
             '"long_url": "'+websiteToshorten+'",' +
             '"domain": "bit.ly",' +
             '"group_guid": ""' +
          '}'
        );

        Http http = new Http();   
        HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
        System.debug(res.getBody());    
        Map<String, Object> b = (Map<String,Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(res.getBody());
        system.debug(b.get('link'));
        
        return String.valueOf(b.get('link'));   
    }       
}
```

Can anyone please help me out with this issue?

Comment: NamedCredential is supposed to take care of the authentication. Why are you setting Authorization header in your web request?

Answer (score 0):

First, don't set the Authorization header when using the Generate Authorization Header option on Named Credentials.

Second, if you are using an Authorization header, the token is sensitive to spaces; your header should have been:

```
req.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer ...');
```

Notice how I removed the space at the beginning. This can make a difference.

Comment: I have removed the Authorization header but still facing the same issue

Comment: @TanviThakur Did you check Generate Authorization Header on the Named Credentials?

Comment: Yes it is checked